# Como obtener la url actual en Twig en Symfony

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3, symfony, twig

Necesito obtener la ruta final de la url en `twig`

Por ejemplo tengo esta url:

`http://www.hackeruna.com/pagina`, yo solo necesito esta parte de la ruta `/pagina`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de obtener la url actual en `symfony` desde `Twig` es:

Url relativa:

```
{{ app.request.pathinfo }}
```

Url absoluta:

```
{{ app.request.pathinfo }}
```

Para resolver mi problema también existe la opción:

```
{{ app.request.pathinfo }}
```